# Custom back button disappears after setting navigation bar background image

Tags: iphone, image, invisible, navigationbar

I'm using the following categories code to change 
the background image of the navigation bar

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void) setBackgroundImage:(UIImage*)image;
- (void) clearBackgroundImage;
@end


#import "UINavigationBar+CustomImage.h"

@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void) setBackgroundImage:(UIImage*)image {
    if (image == NULL) return;
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    [self insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
    [imageView release];
}

- (void) clearBackgroundImage {    
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSArray *mySubviews = [self subviews];

    for (int i = [mySubviews count] - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if ([[mySubviews objectAtIndex:i] isMemberOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
        {
            [[mySubviews objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
            return;
        }
    }

    [pool release];
}
@end
```

And i'm using the following code to generate the custom back button
in my view

```
UIButton *btnBack = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
[btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btnBack setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *barBtnBack = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnBack];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barBtnBack;

[btnBack release];
[barBtnBack release];
```

But the button most of the time is hidden under the bg image
and some times it randomly appears.
Why is this happening? I'm not sure what's the problem the image is inserted at index 0 
so as I understand it is supposed to be behind all the time.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should try creating the button after adding the image.

Comment: But that's what i'm doing     [[dataCenter.navController navigationBar] performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setBackgroundImage:) withObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"headerlogo.png"]]; Then adding the button

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to change background of the navigation bar in the class where you are loading the navigation bar.

```
@interface UINavigationBar (MyCustomNavBar)
@end
@implementation UINavigationBar (MyCustomNavBar)
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    UIImage *barImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png" ];
    [barImage drawInRect:rect];
}
@end
```

Comment: I've used this code before but the image should change between views, can I do that with this function?

Comment: For between views you can keep a value to track it.

Comment: I put the code in the .m file of the AppDelegate and used a global variable and i'm calling the function with this code:     [[center.navController navigationBar] performSelectorInBackground:@selector(drawRect:) withObject:nil];
 but the image is not changing, should I remove the previous one first?

Comment: Put in where you are creating the nav controller

Comment: I'm not sure where you mean? i'm creating the nav in appDelegate

Comment: Write it in the view class which will be loaded into the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Using the method Praveen S suggested you could have a global variable for the next background image name and set it in your viewDidLoad method, then in your draw rect method use the imageName stored in the variable rather than hardcoding it in the draw rect.